# insert into table from empty table fails in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

In HQL script i have insert into step which inserts data from another table, issue I am facing is another table on somedays might be having no records.

Query: `insert into table table1 select * from table2;`

Issue: table2 above might be empty i.e. no rows in table.
Error faced:

> FAILED: Executing Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exe.mr.MapRedTask (state=08S01, code=2)

Can anyone please tell me how to i handle this situation, I believe its due to table2 being without any records.

Comment: The error message is not informative. Study the jobtracker logs for failed container to find the exact reason of failure.

Comment: table2 if it has rows its works, where as when without rows it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting data check data available in table 2.

If data is available insert into table 1

```
IF Exists ( select * from table2)
BEGIN

     - - insert statement goes here.

END
```

Comment: Hive doesn't have begin/end